# Setting proxy attribute in Jax-WS (SOAP)

Tags: soap, proxy, cxf, jax-ws

Is there a way in java to set proxy attributes when using a JAX-WS SOAP ? 
I'm using apache cxf-codegen-plugin to generate classes from a wsdl. I wonder if it is possible to intercept a the request in order to set the proxy.

Anyone can help about that or guide me to find how to intercept a soap connection / request and set the corporate proxy parameters ?

PS: Please note that For my case it is not possible to use a customer proxy selector.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this using XML configuration: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Theclientelement

Comment: Thanks. But I need something that allows to choose to apply a well loaded proxy or not. That XML configuration forces to use the declared proxy on every soap request I suppose.

Comment: Ok you mean you want to set it programmatically? On the same page is an example for it: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Usingjavacode